# Erro 500 no couchdb

Tags: couchdb

Estou com desenvolvendo um app utilizando AngularJs + CouchDb. Mas apesar de toda velocidade que o couchdb oferece conforme vou utilizando o app de repente o a conexão com o couchdb cai retornando o seguinte erro:

```
{"status":500,"name":"unknown_error","message":"Database encountered an unknown error"}"
```

Já fiz alguns ajustes no Config do couch com o intuito de resolver mas ainda não tive sucesso algum.

Seria de muita ajuda se alguém pudesse me dar uma forcinha de como solucionar isso.

Comment: O `CouchDB` está em uma máquina remota ou na sua máquina local?

Comment: O couch está em um servidor remoto. Já configurei os Corns e etc, mas infelizmente continua dando esse erro.